# How to catch-all tables in TOML file with toml-rs library in Rust

Tags: rust

New to Rust! Currently, I am playing around with toml-rs library to read TOML configuration.

See [my code on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f577721aeac29348c96c6e0b699a40e)

Here's code that I took from toml-rs' examples/decode.rs and updated the code

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use toml;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    active_users: Vec<String>,
    // john: Option<User>, - i don't want to manually add each line for all tables
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let toml_str = r#"
        active_users = ["john", "new2rust"]
        
        [john]
        name = "John Doe"
        
        [new2rust]
        name = "Jane Doe"
        
        [randomguy]
        name = "Rust Guy"
    "#;

    let decoded: Config = toml::from_str(toml_str).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", decoded);
}
```

**output**

```
Config {
    active_users: [
        "john",
        "new2rust",
    ],
}
```

My desired output would be like this

```
Config {
    active_users: [
        "john",
        "new2rust",
    ],
    john: ...,
    new2rust: ...,
    randomguy: ...,
}
```

I don't want to manually add each line `john: Option<User>` to Config for all other tables since configuration will be updated frequently. So I am not sure how to catch all tables and add them to Config with toml-rs.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make much sense, why are individual users struct members? Does that mean you need to recompile the application any time you want to add a new user? [Why not use `serde(flatten)` and collect them in a hashmap keyed by login](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8557d338342ba5dd2704acff5870984a)?

Comment: Alternatively, have an explicit `user` or `users` table, as mixing namespaces can cause trouble for future evolutions (what if one of your users wants to be called `active_users`?) But that depends on the status of the project (beware tho throw-away one-offs have a tendency to stick around IME). An other alternative would be to get rid of the `active_users` array and make it a user-level flag, that way you have *just* a hashmap of users. Obviously that means you can't have top-level global config anymore. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

**There's definitely a way to do what you're describing, but it's not necessary, and not a good idea.**

Like mentioned in the comments, you're basically hardcoding your users because of them being their own fields in the struct. Instead of misusing the rest of the tables in the file you should use an array of tables (https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#array-of-tables).

*As also mentioned you can use serde's flatten, but that's not what you want and honestly just going to lead you down the wrong road while trying to learn Rust.*

Then your markup would look like this:

```ini
active_users = [ { name = "john" }, { name = "new2rust" } ]
```

And your deserialization structs would look like this:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    active_users: Vec<User>,
}
```